# Simple Apache mod_rewrite remapping

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have to remap a few ID's to URL strings (301 redirect) and I have to do it with mod_rewrite:

```
/page.php?id=15 to /pagexy
/page.php?id=10 to /pageyz
```

The rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page.php?id=15$  /pagexy   [L,R=301]
```

doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the query string separately. The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=15\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^/page.php$ /pagexy? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=10\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^/page.php$ /pageyz? [L,R=301]
```

Given you are tying ids to pages, it may also pay to look at using a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html)